# What is the winding behavior of the Riemann zeta function around zero along the line $s=1+it$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $\phi: \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \to S^1 \subset \mathbb C$ be defined by
$$\phi(t)= \zeta(1+it)/|\zeta(1+it)|$$
(the nonvavishing of the denominator being a bit weaker than the prime number theorem).

**Question 1:** Does $\phi$ preferentially wind in one direction or the other?

**Question 2:** How does the absolute value of the winding number of $\phi$ grow with $t$?

What else can be said about the statistics here?

Comment: This paper by Lamzouri https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2439537 may answer your questions (see also the later work of Lamzouri, Lester, and Radziwill https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4041109 )

Comment: Isn't $\zeta(1+it)$ always in the right half-plane?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: No. See the responses here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80973/lower-bound-for-re-zeta1it