# Finite sum seemingly related to nontrivial zeta zeros

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ define
$$ F(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{[t]} \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n^{\frac12 + it}}$$

Let $\operatorname{Arg}(t)$ be $\operatorname{atan2}(\Im t , \Re t)$ -
basically this is $\arctan$, but the sign depends on the quadrant.

**Observation** $\operatorname{Arg}(F(t))$ jumps (usually from negative
to positive) very near all nontrivial zeta zeros on the critical line
and in seemingly rare occasions without zeros. Computing $F(t)$ the
naiive way is not efficient for me.

$F(t)$ is truncated Dirichlet eta function on the critical line,
but it is not $0$ at zeros of zeta, though $|F(t)|$ has local minima near zeros.

**Added** Wolfram Alpha found [closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(-1)%5E(n-1)/n%5E(1/2+i*t)%20n%20from%201%20to%20k)
for $F(t)$ in terms of Hurwitz zeta and zeta:

\begin{align} 
& \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\frac12 + i t}} = \\ 
& 2^{-1/2-i t}(-(-1)^k \zeta(i t+1/2, (k+1)/2)+ \\
& (-1)^k \zeta(i t+1/2, (k+2)/2)+2^{1/2+i t} \zeta(1/2 i (2  t-i))-2 \zeta(1/2 i (2 t-i)))
\end{align}

Setting $k=[t]$ gives $F(t)$. Numerical evidence supports the closed form.

In comments Greg Martin suggested $F(t)$ might not be correlated to
higher zeros, though numerical evidence suggests it is correlated
at height $10^6$, including closely spaced zeros.

Another observation is $|F(t)|$ appears to have local minima
close to zeta zeros on the critical line.

Setting $$ G(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{[t]} \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n^{1 + it}}$$

the jumps of $G(t)$ appear zeros of $\eta(1+i t)$ and looks like
$|G(t)| \sim |\eta(1 + i t)|$

> Can this be explained?
>
> Counterexamples?

Plot:

[image]

Closely spaced zeros and modulus
[image]

$t=10^6$.
[image]

Comment: I imagine $F(t)$ will be correlated with the first several zeros (the larger $t$ is, the more zeros will be involved) but that eventually it will be more or less completely agnostic about high-up zeros. One could probably make this rigorous using a trace formula of some kind.

Comment: @GregMartin There is closed form for $F(t)$ in terms of Hurwitz zeta and zeta, edited the question. The modulus appears related to zeros too and it works for $t=10^6$ and closely spaced zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is mysterious.  The function $F(t)$ is a partial sum for the "$\eta$-function"
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{1/2+i t}}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)
$$
a function which converges conditionally, and uniformly for $t$ in a compact set.  Now $F(t)$ has discontinuities due to the truncation $[t]$.  However, for large $t$ where the density of zeros of $\eta$ is $2\pi/\log(t)$ we will see many zeros in between each discontinuity.

The function $\eta(1/2+it)$ will trace out a curve in the complex plane, passing repeatedly through the origin.  It's argument will have a discontinuity of $+\pi$ each time (I'm assuming RH here.)  Since $F(t)$ tracks this function closely, it's argument will change rapidly, even when $F(t)$ does not pass through the origin.

The places where $\arg F(t)$ seems to jump away from a Riemann zero are more mysterious, but I would first consider the possibility the $\arg$ code is lying to you.

Comment: Thank you Stopple. I wrote it is truncated eta too. How do you explain local minima of |F(t)| are approximations of zeros without known counterexamples so far? And for "how large $t$" do you expect counterexamples (so far it works for t=10^6 for closely spaced zeros). More mysterious to me are closely spaced zeros.

Comment: @joro: The answer to your question about the local minima of $|F(t)|$ is exactly the same: $|F(t)|$ is a good approximation to $\eta(1/2+i t)$.  In contrast to what Greg Martin argues, I'm claiming this does not fail for large $t$; in fact the approximation gets better.

Comment: The arg jump far away from zero on the first plot might be explained by $\Im \eta(1/2+it)=0$

Comment: The plot jumps from (about) $-\pi$ to (about) $+\pi$ near $1006.5$.  This happens when the function crosses the negative $x$ axis, it's the defined behavior of atan2:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: And the reason such things are rare is related to this answer:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73098/negative-values-of-riemann-zeta-function-on-the-critical-line/73100#73100

Answer (score 1):

About the local minima approximating zeros, have you considered Hurwitz theorem? if the limit of the sequence of partial sums is 0 (not identically), then, in a disk close neighbourhood of the concerned zero, each nth partial sum with n greater than an index k (k depending on the size of said disk) would feature a zero. Perhaps, your minima correspond indeed to said zeroes ... of course, in general, to exactly hit zero, instead of a minimum just close to it, you will have to move within said disk also a bit away from the critical line.